# Couldn't resolve variable issue Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm not much of an Objective-C guy I primarily use swift and I need some help from this error

> Variable 'indexOfLargestGap' may be uninitialized when used here

and

> Variable 'indexOfSmallestGap' may be uninitialized when used here

I have imported the code from Github and created a bridging header and fixed a few errors but I don't know how to fix this one.

The original file from Github https://github.com/jberlana/JBCroppableView

```
#import "JBCroppableImageView.h"
#import "JBCroppableLayer.h"


@implementation JBCroppableImageView{
    JBCroppableLayer *_pointsView;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _pointsView = [[JBCroppableLayer alloc] initWithImageView:self];
        [_pointsView addPoints:4];

        [self addSubview:_pointsView];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *singlePan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singlePan:)];
        singlePan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:singlePan];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *doublePan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doublePan:)];
        doublePan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:doublePan];


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)singlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    CGPoint posInStretch = [gesture locationInView:_pointsView];
    if(gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        [_pointsView findPointAtLocation:posInStretch];
    }
    if(gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        _pointsView.activePoint.backgroundColor = _pointsView.pointColor;
        _pointsView.activePoint = nil;
    }
    [_pointsView moveActivePointToLocation:posInStretch];
    //  CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.imageView];
    //  [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.imageView];
}

-(void)doublePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    NSLog(@"double pan");
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self];
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x+translation.x, self.center.y+translation.y);
    [self setCenter:newCenter];
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];

}

-(void)crop{
    [_pointsView maskImageView:self];
    [_pointsView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)reverseCrop{
    self.layer.mask = nil;
    [self addSubview:_pointsView];
}

-(UIImage *)getCroppedImage{
   return [_pointsView getCroppedImageForView:self withTransparentBorders:NO];
}

-(UIImage *)getCroppedImageWithTransparentBorders:(BOOL)transparent{
    return [_pointsView getCroppedImageForView:self withTransparentBorders:transparent];
}

- (void)addPoint{
    self.layer.mask = nil;
    NSMutableArray *oldPoints = [_pointsView.getPoints mutableCopy];
    // CGPoint new = CGPointMake((first.x+last.x)/2.0f, (first.y+last.y)/2.0f);

    NSInteger indexOfLargestGap; //points to here for first warning
    CGFloat largestGap = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< oldPoints.count-1; i++){
        CGPoint first = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint last = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue];
        CGFloat distance = [self distanceBetween:first And:last];
        if(distance>largestGap){
            indexOfLargestGap = i+1;
            largestGap = distance;
        }
    }
    CGPoint veryFirst = [[oldPoints firstObject] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint veryLast = [[oldPoints lastObject] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint new;

    if([self distanceBetween:veryFirst And:veryLast]>largestGap){
        indexOfLargestGap = oldPoints.count;
        new = CGPointMake((veryFirst.x+veryLast.x)/2.0f, (veryFirst.y+veryLast.y)/2.0f);
    } else {
        CGPoint first = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:indexOfLargestGap-1] CGPointValue];//Variable 'indexOfLargestGap' may be uninitialized when used here
        CGPoint last = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:indexOfLargestGap] CGPointValue];
        new = CGPointMake((first.x+last.x)/2.0f, (first.y+last.y)/2.0f);
    }


    [oldPoints insertObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:new] atIndex:indexOfLargestGap];
    [_pointsView removeFromSuperview];
    _pointsView = [[JBCroppableLayer alloc] initWithImageView:self];
    [_pointsView addPointsAt:oldPoints];
    [self addSubview:_pointsView];
}

- (void)removePoint{
    self.layer.mask = nil;
    NSMutableArray *oldPoints = [_pointsView.getPoints mutableCopy];
    if(oldPoints.count==3) return;

    NSInteger indexOfSmallestGap;// points to here for second warning
    CGFloat smallestGap = INFINITY;
    for(int i=0; i< oldPoints.count; i++){
        int firstIndex = i-1;
        int lastIndex = i +1;

        if(firstIndex<0){
            firstIndex = (int)oldPoints.count-1+firstIndex;
        } else if(firstIndex>=oldPoints.count){
            firstIndex = firstIndex-(int)oldPoints.count;
        }
        if(lastIndex<0){
            lastIndex = (int)oldPoints.count-1+lastIndex;
        } else if(lastIndex>=oldPoints.count){
            lastIndex = lastIndex-(int)oldPoints.count;
        }

        CGPoint first = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:firstIndex] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint mid = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint last = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:lastIndex] CGPointValue];
        CGFloat distance = [self distanceFrom:first to:last throuh:mid];
        if(distance<smallestGap){
            indexOfSmallestGap = i;
            smallestGap = distance;
        }
    }

    [oldPoints removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfSmallestGap]; //Variable 'indexOfSmallestGap' may be uninitialized when used here
    [_pointsView removeFromSuperview];
    _pointsView = [[JBCroppableLayer alloc] initWithImageView:self];
    [_pointsView addPointsAt:[NSArray arrayWithArray:oldPoints]];
    [self addSubview:_pointsView];
}

-(CGFloat)distanceBetween:(CGPoint)first And:(CGPoint)last{
    CGFloat xDist = (last.x - first.x);
    if(xDist<0) xDist=xDist*-1;
    CGFloat yDist = (last.y - first.y);
    if(yDist<0) yDist=yDist*-1;
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}
-(CGFloat)distanceFrom:(CGPoint)first to:(CGPoint)last throuh:(CGPoint)middle{
    CGFloat firstToMid = [self distanceBetween:first And:middle];
    CGFloat lastToMid = [self distanceBetween:middle And:last];
    return   firstToMid + lastToMid;
}

-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [_pointsView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [_pointsView setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

And I'm getting this from the terminal

> index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: Why don't you rewrite it to swift? It's fairly straightforward and it will be easier to find the error for you. It would guess there are no points. Maybe you are not initializing the object correctly? Are you using the designated initializer? This class is made to be initialized only from `xib` or `storyboard`.  Are you trying to initialize it manually?

Comment: The message is very clear.  Hint: What happens in `addPoint` if `distance` is never greater than `largestGap`? What is the value of `indexOfLargestGap` after the `for` loop in this case?

Comment: The reason why you are getting the errors you mention is because the variable `indexOfSmallestGap` has never been initialized before being used. In Swift you never get these warnings because Swift doesn't even let you compile an uninitialized variable. So just initialize it with, say, zero, and that warning will go away. Concerning your out-of-bounds error, it can be many things... and just maybe due to the fact that you do not have initialized indexOfSmallestGap. Do that and try again. If does not work, just tell us when you get this error: when you add or when you remove points?

Comment: @Sulthan I would have to do it manually because I'm not using storyboard my project is written programmatically.

Comment: @jvarela yeah, it was initialized to nothing. I just set it to zero and the error disappeared thanks.

Comment: @BisqqA You will have to change that `initWithCoder` to `initWithFrame` then, otherwise the view is not really initialized. `initWithCoder` is called only when initializing from Interface Builder files. The author of the file should have written both designated initializers, not just one. Again, a thing that would not happen in Swift where you have to override both.